# APEX 5 link Modal Page in IR cell

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I work on APEX 5 application and want to have link to modal page in IR. When I put in select `select '<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION.">' || col1 || '</a>' col1, ...` get an error **ORA-00911: invalid character**, but if I change page 2 from Modal to Normal everything is fine. Where do I make mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement links to modal page using declarative approach rather than deriving it using query. This can be done by changing the column type to Link and then mention link target and link text, screenshot below:

[image]

If this does not work for you and you want to do it through query then use **APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL** function is your query like this,

```
SELECT
    COL1, 
    COL2, 
    '<a href="' || APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(P_URL => 'f?p=' || V('APP_ID') || ':2:' || V('APP_SESSION'), P_CHECKSUM_TYPE => 'SESSION') || '">' || COL1 || '</a>' LINK 
FROM 
    TABLE1
```

More Information on PREPARE_URL function can be found here --> [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/PREPARE_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI160)

Comment: Yes, you are right but the both way I get the error: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small. That is the reason I tried to replace declarative approach  with using query. I have 31 columns for 31 days in month. Every column has value as number from 0 to 10. It works for 25 days but when I change 26. column from Plain Text to Link  I get error character string buffer too small.It's the same when I use link in query.

Comment: Ohh, I think you should add your data issue as separate question. I am sure someone has a way to work around this issue.